# how to supervise a method in elixir

Tags: elixir

I am trying to supervise a method in elixir. I have this module as `EvercamMedia.SnapshotExtractor.CloudExtractor` as `GenStage` and I am passing some arguments to it such as.

```
def handle_cast({:snapshot_extractor, config}, state) do
  _start_extractor(config)
  {:noreply, [], state}
end
```

this `_strat_extractor` method itself is very very long and has a lot of methods. but In all those methods, there is one which I am using to send HTTPoison request not directly but through A `dropbox` api wrapper.

```
  def upload(200, response, starting, camera_exid, id, requestor) do
    construction =
      case requestor do
        "marklensmen@gmail.com" ->
          "Construction"
        _ ->
          "Construction2"
      end

    image_save_path = "#{@root_dir}/#{camera_exid}/extract/#{id}/#{starting}.jpg"
    path = "#{@root_dir}/#{camera_exid}/extract/#{id}/"
    File.write(image_save_path, response, [:binary]) |> File.close

    client = ElixirDropbox.Client.new(System.get_env["DROP_BOX_TOKEN"])
    {:ok, file_size} = get_file_size(image_save_path)

    try do
      %{"session_id" => session_id} = ElixirDropbox.Files.UploadSession.start(client, true, image_save_path)
      write_sessional_values(session_id, file_size, "/#{construction}/#{camera_exid}/#{id}/#{starting}.jpg", path)
      check_1000_chunk(path) |> length() |> commit_if_1000(client, path)
    rescue
      _ ->
        :timer.sleep(:timer.seconds(3))
        upload(200, response, starting, camera_exid, id, requestor)
    end
  end
  def upload(_, _response, _starting, _camera_exid, _id, _requestor), do: :noop
```

Now,, my question is how I can supervise this method?

Sometimes it gets failed on `ElixirDropbox.Files.UploadSession.start(client, true, image_save_path)` this part. I also have added a supervisor for it, but it's not restarting it when crash, but it just resumes it when an application gets stopped.

How I can make use of `Supervisor` strategies and resume this method when it gets crashed.

```
def upload(200, response, starting, camera_exid, id, requestor) do
```

my supervisor looks like this anyways.

```
defmodule EvercamMedia.SnapshotExtractor.ExtractorSupervisor do

  use Supervisor
  require Logger
  alias EvercamMedia.SnapshotExtractor.Extractor
  alias EvercamMedia.SnapshotExtractor.CloudExtractor
  import Commons

  @root_dir Application.get_env(:evercam_media, :storage_dir)

  def start_link() do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    Task.start_link(&initiate_workers/0)
    extractor_children = [worker(Extractor, [], restart: :permanent)]
    supervise(extractor_children, strategy: :simple_one_for_one, max_restarts: 1_000_000)
    cloud_extractor_childern = [worker(CloudExtractor, [], restart: :permanent)]
    supervise(cloud_extractor_childern, strategy: :simple_one_for_one, max_restarts: 1_000_000)
  end
```

PS: I have tried to add both workers in Child listand passs it to supervise at once but it didnt work as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with `ExtractorSupervisor.init/1`.

```rb
def init(:ok) do
  Task.start_link(&initiate_workers/0)
  children1 = ...
  supervise(children1, ...)
  children2 = ...
  supervise(children2, ...)
end
```

In the first place, you use a legacy deprecated way to [initialize children](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Supervisor.Spec.html#supervise/2) in the supervisor and the [legacy strategy](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/DynamicSupervisor.html?#module-migrating-from-supervisors-simple_one_for_one).

The main problem with this method is that `children1` never get supervised. `Supervisor.Spec.supervise/2` is not a magic wand making processes supervised out of a thin air. It simply [returns the spec](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/99f504e9dcb47875f18dc0b9d52d05d2da47485f/lib/elixir/lib/supervisor/spec.ex#L179) from `init/1` callback, that is understood *by the caller*, which eventually embeds the children into the supervision tree. That means, the first call to `supervise/2` is a noop. To supervise all the children one should do

```rb
def init(:ok) do
  children1 = ...
  children2 = ...

  supervise(children1 ++ children2, ...)
end
```

There might be more glitches, but unless these two are fixed it’s hard to reason about.

*Sidenote:* while it’s somehow legit, I am pretty sure there might be better place to call `Task.start_link/1` rather than `init/1` callback of the supervisor.

Comment: do this change with DynamicSupervisor?